# Why doesnt my session_destroy() works?

Tags: php, session, logout, destroy

Im making a website and I programmed a session so if you dont log in you cant go into some forms but when I log in the session stays in even when I click in the log out button I even made that when it destroy the session it send me to the login again but then it send me to the form that only opens if youre logged in like I never logged out

this is the code I'm using

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:loginusuario.php");
?>
```

heres the code for the login

```
<?php
  include ("conexion/conexion.php");
  include("usuarios.class.php");

$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$clave= $_POST['clave'];



    $objUsuario = new usuarios;
    $srt= $objUsuario->autenticar_usuario($usuario,$clave,1);
    $num =mysql_num_rows($srt);
    if($num <= 0){
        $mensaje="Usuario y/o clave Incorrectos";
         header("location:index.php?mensaje=$mensaje"); 
    }else{

        $row=mysql_fetch_array($srt);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['log'] = 's'; 
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
         header("location:contrataciones.php"); 

    }


?>
```

this is the code for the class

```
<?php 
  class usuarios
  {

    function usuarios() {

    } 
    function autenticar_usuario($usuario,$clave){
        $sel="select usuario,clave from usuarios where usuario='".$usuario."' and clave='".$clave."' ";
        $srt=mysql_query($sel) or die($sel);
        return $srt;

    }

?>
```

I dont know if im missing something or what but I think the code is ok, what do you think?

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with this.

Comment: How do you test is there is an active session in loginusuario.php page ?

Comment: I think you are confused about the concept of sessions. Sessions are always created. You store information in them, like username and stuff. If you want to log out, you can regenerate a new session ID, but also the session variables.

Comment: How you check that users logged-in on your private pages?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your session_destroy(), the problem's probably in the session check that's not supposed to be visible to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to completely destroy a session, and free all associated variables, use it :

```
<?php
    session_start(); //retrieve existing session
    session_unset(); //free all variables
    session_destroy(); //destroy esssion
    session_write_close(); //save session data and close the writing stream (a bit like a SQL commit)
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/'); //if you use cookie : delete it by setting a new one with a 0 lifetime.
    session_regenerate_id(true); //regenerate new session id.
?>
```

Copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php#107089

Comment: does this line go jus like this setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/'); or I gotta write something between the ''?

Comment: Do you use cookies ? This line is optional if not. The second parameter is the cookie value : we set it to an empty string here, since this cookie won't be used. The thing is to replace the existing cookie with one which will be deleted directly, so we don't care about its value. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I dont even know how to use cookies so I think that line is not necessary

Comment: The problem must comes from your loginusuario.php page, the test to know if there is an active session must fail. Please add it to your question.

Answer (score -1):

try:

`session_unset()` before `session_destroy()`
because `session_destroy()` does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.

for more info:
http://www.php.net/function.session-unset

Comment: As written in the documentation you linked : `session_unset — Free all session variables`. OP wants to destroy it.

Comment: Pointless. unset() only applies to session_register()-created values, and that's a DEPRECATED/OBSOLETE method.

Comment: @OlivierH  freeAll ==destroy

Comment: @MarcB **unset()** and **session_unset()** are different

Comment: I was being lazy and ommitted the session_ portion.